# How to specify a fractional framerate with ffmpeg C/C++ when stitching together images?

Tags: c++, c, video, ffmpeg, frame-rate

I want to specify fractional frame rate's like `23.797` or `59.94` when creating my encoder. Here is how I do it currently:

```
AVStream* st;
...
st->time_base = (AVRational){1, STREAM_FRAME_RATE };
```

But looking at ffmpeg's source code at `rational.h` we can see that `AVRational` struct takes int's instead of float's. So my `23.797` turns into 23 thus encoding wrong. How can I specify fps with floating numbers?

Comment: Please see [`av_d2q`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/group__lavu__math__rational.html#ga7dfd5ba1eb1edf5845ac32b338de9e76).

Comment: Do a simple conversion.   i.e. Can you just scale all of your float values by multiplying by 1000, or 10,000, or whatever to preserve the necessary precision, represented by an `int` value?  `23.797` would become `23797`

Comment: @ryyker will it be the same as giving 23797? So all I have to do is to say `st->time_base = (AVRational){1, 23797};` instead of what I was doing so far which is: `st->time_base = (AVRational){1, 23.797 };`

Comment: @G.M. I think this will solve it. There is a parameter called `max` tho, what should I pass as that? I don't want a max value, I don't know what input will be passed by the user. And can you please answer this on top of your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment, you can make use of [`av_d2q`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/group__lavu__math__rational.html#ga7dfd5ba1eb1edf5845ac32b338de9e76) from the `libavutil` library.  By way of a basic example...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

extern "C" {
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
}

int main ()
{
  auto fps = 23.797;
  auto r = av_d2q(1 / fps, std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
  std::cout << "time base is " << r.num << "/" << r.den << " seconds\n";
}
```

The above gives me the following output...

```
time base is 1000/23797 seconds
```